# Adding a preview step to the rails create and update actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, action, preview

This is a part of an app allowing the user to create HTML newsletters. After making edits, I'd like to let them preview the final look before saving the edits.

The preview page would display the preview and add the data in a hidden field to get resubmitted on approval. On "back to editing," the hidden field data would be passed back to the edit view.

I would have to add a "preview" action to the controller.

Is there a simpler way or best practice for this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be good to add a kind of "preview" - Attribute to the model. When you klick on "Preview" you could copy the record or set "preview" to "true" and show it as static page when tis is the case. If the preview is ok, then you could set preview to false and that would state, that the Newsletter is ready to send.

Hope it is clear how i mean it, kinda late for me ;)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was considering this but am worried about leftover "preview" records from abandoned edits. The user makes edits, previews and then navigates somewhere else, closes the browser window etc. On the other hand, it could be a good solution for the concurrent editing pattern (I want to disallow it) -- if a "preview" version exists, this mean someone is already editing. Which doesn't take care of the case when we have two people opening for editing simultaneously, before "preview"-ing. So, I'll need an "open_for_editing_by" attribute, too.